# Shape issue with keras `fit_generator()`

Tags: python, numpy, generator, keras, reshape

I am having a seemingly simple issue with the shape of the numpy arrays returned from a custom generator function I am using within keras's `fit_generator` function.

The generator function is similar to this:

```
def data_generator(full_data, encoder):
    for s in full_data:
        in1_X = encoder.encode(s[:,0])
        in2_X = encoder.encode(s[:,1])
        out1_y = encoder.encode(s[:,2])
        out2_y = encoder.encode(s[:,3])
        X = [in1_X, in2_X]
        y = [out1_y, out2_y]
        yield (X,y)
```

I can get the shape returned from in1_X by using a for loop and printing the shape, which simply returns `(60,)`

However, when calling this using the `fit_generator()` function, it fails:

```
train_data_gen = data_generator(full_data, encoder)


main_in = Input(shape=(seq_len,), name='main_input')

# ...
# define model
# ...

joint_model.fit_generator(train_data_gen, steps_per_epoch=2000, epochs=2)
```

from which the output is this:

```
Error when checking input: 
expected main_input to have shape (None, 60) but got array with shape (60, 1)
```

How can I get this to not change the numpy array from shape `(60,)` to shape `(60, 1)`?  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: The expensive duct tape is to flatten. in1_x = in1_x.flatten() etc. as your encoder seems to return a 2D array.

Comment: We are facing the same problem. To flatten does not make a difference - it provides the same shape as without flattening. From our experience, we invoke the generator and evaluate shapes, and receive the expected one: x, y = my_generator.next()
print("next[x]: {}".format(x.shape))#shape is (517,) in our case, but when feeding, we get the error "expected main_input to have shape (None, 517) but got array with shape (517, 1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a response to this issue. Please check the explanation and comments at the following PR: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4641
Providing a 2D array solved the issue for us.